# How can I create a property for a special vertex type in JanusGraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to add a property for a specific vertex type. Assuming I have `person` and `car` vertex types in my graph schema, how can I add the `name` and `birthday` properties only to the `person` vertex?

Example of creating `firstName` property:

```
graph.openManagement().makePropertyKey('firstName')
     .dataType‌​(String.class).cardi‌​nality(Cardinality.S‌​INGLE).make();
```

Here I am creating new property of vertex but How can I restrict it to a specific type of vertex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show what you have? What have you tried?

Comment: graph.openManagement().makePropertyKey('firstName').dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();

Here I am creating new property of vertex but How can i specify to which type of verteces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the new JanusGraph 0.3.0 release, it is now possible to create schema constraints which do exactly what you want. Since those constraints are disabled by default, they first need to be enabled by setting `schema.constraints` to `true`. Now you can create a constraint like this:

```
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
person = mgmt.makeVertexLabel('person').make()
name = mgmt.makePropertyKey('firstName').dataType(String.class).
    cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
mgmt.addProperties(person, name)
mgmt.commit()
```

which means that the `firstName` property key can only be used on a vertex with the label `person`.

When you now try to add this property to a vertex with a different label, then it will throw an exception:

```
gremlin> g.addV('car').property('firstName','test')
Property Key constraint does not exist for given Vertex Label [car] and property key [firstName].
```

See the [official JanusGraph documentation on schema constraints](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/schema.html#schema-constraints) for more information.

*I updated my answer as it stated before that schema constraints would not yet be possible which they now are.*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and I will track the progress.